# Customize gradle task's strict order of execution through projects / modules

Tags: gradle, groovy

I have the following dir structure

```
myproj/
   - build.gradle
   - settings.gradle
subproj1/
   - build.gradle
subproj2/
   - build.gradle
```

When I execute

`gradle customTask`

I want my customTask to execute **completely** inside `subproj2` and then synchronously after **it finished inside subproj2** to move on and execute custom task inside `subproj1`

**My current configuration (I tried to define subproj2 as dependency to subproj1):**

**myproj - settings.gradle**

```
rootProject.name = 'wowsuchwowproject'    
include ':subproj1', ':subproj2'
```

**myproj - build.gradle**

```
project(":subproj1") {

}

project(":subproj2") {

}
```

**subproj1 - build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    api project(":subproj2")
}

task("customTask") {
    ...
}
```

**subproj2 - build.gradle**

```
task("customTask") {
    ...
}
```

But I'm getting this error; what am I missing?

```
* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':subproj1:mergeReleaseResources'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':subproj1:releaseRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve project :subproj2.
     Required by:
         project :subproj1
      > Unable to find a matching configuration of project :subproj2: None of the consumable configurations have attributes.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

**UPDATE 10/01/2019: added plugin info**

These are the other things I have in the root `build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```

In all the others I have

```
apply plugin: com.myown.plugin.AwesomePlugin
```

Comment: Can you please add information on the applied plugins in these projects?

Comment: I can’t reproduce this, even when adding `allprojects { apply plugin: 'java-library' }` to the root project. So as @LouisJacomet said, you’ll have to provide more details on your build configuration.